# How i can reload/restart service in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

How can I restart a service without reloading an app?

I do not want to use `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: `window.location.reload()` will reload your application... You can't 'restart' your service without doing so...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by restart? As it is singleton it happens only once.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a factory instead of simple service and create a `reset` method on it which would set it to its "initial state".

For example, your factory could look something like this:

```
function MyFactory() {

    // generate the initial structure of the service
    let Factory = _getDefaultFactory();

    // expose the service properties and methods
    return Factory;

    /**
     * Reset the factory back to its default state
     */
    function reset() {
        // generate the initial structure again
        // and override the current structure of the service
        Factory = _getDefaultFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Generate a default service structure
     */
    function _getDefaultFactory() {

        return {

            // include the reset method so you can call it later
            // e.g. MyFactory.reset();
            reset: reset

            // include other factory properties and methods here

        };

    }

}
```