# Better way to initialize all the global services when user Logged out

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to clear all data or initialize all the global services when the user Logged out. So I have used `window.location.reload();` and it does the job. But can I have a better approach here since my current hack gives bad UI/UX to the user?

```
  private refreshTheApp(): void {
   
      window.location.reload();
    
  }
```

The problem is with this kind of global Singleton service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventDataService {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How i can reload/restart service in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383581/how-i-can-reload-restart-service-in-angular)

Comment: @DanielKlischies No. It is for `AngularJS`.

Comment: I usually have an `AppEventsService` that has some `Subject<...>` (private but exported as observables) so that when the user logs out I do something like `this.appEventsService.emitLoggedOutEvent()` (which emits using the right subject) and in other services and pages I just subscribe to `this.appEventsService.loggedOut$.subscribe(() => { ... })`.

It's not a very clever approach but it allows different pages and services to do whatever they need when the event happens.

Comment: I've also used a more elaborate event system where each event can have a typed payload which makes things easier when the event also involves sending a payload (instead of using `any` or `unknown`) but it's a bit more complicated to be explained in a comment — I could write an answer if you think it could be useful :)

Comment: @sebaferreras Please put that as an answer. I also have a lot of data services like so you explained. So I can get something from your approach here.

Comment: The answer I posted also works for any newer angular version. Use a factory instead of a Singelton. Let the Factory cache whatever is your Singleton, and always return that. Then add a reset method to your factory, such that you can erase the stored Singelton. This, of course, still requires that all components are reinitalized, such that the new singleton is injected. This could be achieved by telling the router to navigate. If all you want is to reset data, then an reactive approach as outlined by @sebaferreras is going to be a less of a hassle. But that will require switching to observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simplest Approach

The simplest approach would involve having something like an `AppEventsService` with a few subjects exported as observables so that any component/service could subscribe to its changes.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppEventsService {
  public userSignOut$: Observable<void>;
  private userSignOut$$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor() {
    this.userSignOut$ = this.userSignOut$$.asObservable();
  }

  public emitUserSignOutEvent(): void {
    this.userSignOut$$.next();
  }
}
```

That way when the user signs out you can call `this.appEventsService. emitUserSignOutEvent()` and any other service/component can subscribe to this event like `this.appEventsService.userSignOut$.subscribe(() => {...})`

### More elaborated approach

A better approach could be to have something like an app events system where each event has a type and a **typed** payload. Please take a look at this [Github repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/app-events-demo/tree/main/src/app).

**IMPORTANT: This is just a demo and there's definitely a lot of room for improvements!!!**

The basic elements from this demo are the events, a custom filter operator and the `AppEventsService`.

**1) Events**

Defining an event is a bit verbose but the benefit is that the payload of the event will be typed.

For example, the following code defines the `UserSignInEvent`:

```
import { BaseEvent } from './base.event';

export const USER_SIGN_IN = 'USER_SIGN_IN';

// Event definition
export interface UserSignInEvent {
  type: typeof USER_SIGN_IN;
  payload: {
    id: number;
    email: string;
  };
}

// Event creator function
export const userSignInEvent = (
  id: number,
  email: string
): UserSignInEvent => ({
  type: USER_SIGN_IN,
  payload: { id, email },
});

// Event filtering function
export const isUserSignInEvent = (event: BaseEvent): event is UserSignInEvent =>
  event.type === USER_SIGN_IN;
```

The code above not only defines the event, but also defines a function that allows us to create an instance of the event, and another function that allows us to recognise the event based on its `type`. They will be used later when dispatching and subscribing to the event.

**2) Filter operator**

This operator allows us (obviously) to filter the events based on its type so that each subscriber could listen to specific events. But the operator also makes its payload to be typed:

```
import { OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const filterEvent =
  <T, R extends T>(guard: (value: T) => value is R): OperatorFunction<T, R> =>
  (source) =>
    source.pipe(
      map((value) => {
        if (guard(value)) {
          return value;
        }

        return null;
      }),
      filter((value) => !!value)
    );
```

**3) The service**

This is a very simple service exposes a method to dispatch events and another method to subscribe to specific events:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { BaseEvent } from '../events/base.event';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppEventsService {
  private eventsDispatcher = new Subject<BaseEvent>();

  public dispatch(event: BaseEvent): void {
    this.eventsDispatcher.next(event);
  }

  public get onEvents$(): Observable<BaseEvent> {
    return this.eventsDispatcher.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**Using the events**

Dispatching an event is super simple thanks to the function that help us to create instances of the events:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { userSignInEvent, userSignOutEvent } from 'src/app/events';
import { AppEventsService } from 'src/app/services/app-events.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab2Page {
  constructor(private appEventsService: AppEventsService) {}

  public dispatchSignInEvent(): void {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    const email = `test+${id}@user.com`;

    console.log(`===> TAB 2: about to dispatch UserSingInEvent: ${id} - ${email}`);
    this.appEventsService.dispatch(userSignInEvent(id, email));
  }

  public dispatchSignOutEvent(): void {
    console.log(`===> TAB 2: about to dispatch UserSingOutEvent`);
    this.appEventsService.dispatch(userSignOutEvent());
  }
}
```

And then the last part of the code is to subscribe to these events.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { isUserSignInEvent, isUserSignOutEvent } from 'src/app/events';
import { filterEvent } from 'src/app/operators';
import { AppEventsService } from 'src/app/services/app-events.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public id: number;
  public email: string;
  public isSignedIn: boolean;

  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private appEventsService: AppEventsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appEventsService.onEvents$
      .pipe(filterEvent(isUserSignInEvent), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(({ payload }) => {
        const { id, email } = payload;

        console.log(`===> TAB 1: received UserSingInEvent: ${id} - ${email}`);

        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.isSignedIn = true;
      });

    this.appEventsService.onEvents$
      .pipe(filterEvent(isUserSignOutEvent), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(`===> TAB 1: received UserSingOutEvent`);

        this.id = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.isSignedIn = false;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The most important part of that code is this one:

```
  this.appEventsService.onEvents$
      .pipe(filterEvent(isUserSignInEvent)) // <----
      .subscribe(({ payload }) => {
        // the payload is typed here!
      });
```

Thanks to the `filterEvent` operator and the `isUserSignInEvent` function the event's payload is typed :)